# Bind function pointer to boost::function object

Tags: c++, function-pointers, boost-bind, boost-function, function-object

How can I initialize a `boost::function` object with a raw function pointer?

**Metacode**

```
extern "C"
{
    class Library
    {
        ...
    };
    Library* createLibrary();
}
```

...

```
void* functionPtr = library.GetFunction("createLibrary");
boost::function<Library*()> functionObj(functionPtr);

Library* libInstance = functionObj();
```

If you need additional information's just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void*` is not a function pointer, so you can't create a `boost::function` from it. You probably want to convert this to a proper function pointer first. How to do that is implementation dependent.

This is how this ugly conversion is recommended in POSIX ([rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html#tag_03_112_08)):

```
void* ptr = /* get it from somewhere */;
Library* (*realFunctionPointer)(); // declare a function pointer variable
*(void **) (&realFunctionPointer) = ptr // hack a void* into that variable
```

Your platform may require different shenanigans.

Once you have such a pointer you can simply do:

```
boost::function<Library*()> functionObj(realFunctionPtr);

Library* libInstance = functionObj();
```

Comment: Is there a platform independent way to do this?

Comment: @Mythli: No. Like I said, converting a `void*` to a function pointer is platform dependent. If you have access to a real function pointer inside `GetFunction`, you may be able to refactor it into templates and avoid `void*`, and thus skip all the platform-specific nasties.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting your answer directly but I was not at home for a long time and therefore couldn't test it.

Comment: @Mythli Hey, no need to apologize. I'm glad it helped out.

Answer (score 0):

with boost::bind you can literly bind functions to a boost function object.

```
boost::function</*proper function pointer type*/> functionObj = boost::bind(functionPtr);
```